# php update values of an array based on other array with the same key

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have the following scenario:

```
$starterArray = array ('192.168.3.41:8013'=>0,'192.168.3.41:8023'=>0,'192.168.3.41:8033'=>0);
```

In the requirement I have another array which counts some events of the application, this array uses the same keys as my first array, but values can change), so at the end I could have something like:

```
$processArray = array ('192.168.3.41:8013'=>3,'192.168.3.41:8023'=>5,'192.168.3.41:8033'=>7);
```

I want to update the values of my starter array with the values of the process array, for instance, at the end, I should have:

```
$starterArray = array ('192.168.3.41:8013'=>3,'192.168.3.41:8023'=>5,'192.168.3.41:8033'=>7);
```

I know this can be achieved by using `$starterArray = $processArray;`

Then in some moments, I would need to sum some units to the values of my array, for example +1 or +2:

It should be something like the following?

```
foreach ($starterArray as $key => $value) {
    $starterArray[$value] = $starterArray[$value]+1;
}
```

Then, for my process array, I need to set the values to 0

```
foreach ($processArray as $key => $value) {
    $processArray[$value] = 0;
}
```

This is what I tried but it is not working, if somebody could help me I will really appreaciate it. Thanks in advance.

PD: I know these are strange requirements, but that's what I am asked to do...

Comment: The PHP manual has examples for `foreach` that should help you. In particular, you are using `[$value]` instead of `[$key]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:-

```
foreach ($processArray as $key => $value) {
    $starterArray[$key] = $value +1;
}
```

and then:-

```
foreach ($processArray as $key => $value) {
    $processArray[$key] = 0;
}
```

However, you could do this all in one loop:-

```
foreach ($processArray as $key => $value) {
    $starterArray[$key] = $value +1;
    $processArray[$key] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `$key` in brackets, not `$value`.

Or, you can do:

```
foreach ($starterArray as $key => &$value) {
    $value++; /* put here whatever formula you want */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($starterArray as $key => $value) {
    $starterArray[$key] = $value+1;
    // or $starterArray[$key] = 0;
}
```